# UTF-8 words not display in laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I write a simple code for rendering chinese words in pdf. But the chinese words does not appear.

This is my code.

```
Route::get('/pdf', function () {
    $html = '<html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p style="font-family: firefly, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;">献给母亲的爱</p>
                </body>
                </html>';
   $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->stream();
});
```

I'm using

```
1) PHP 7.1.1
2) Laravel 5.3
```

I inserted the meta into the header and change the font. What might gone wrong here?please help thanks.

Comment: Did you set the PHP header and check the file-encoding too?

Comment: I check file-encoding for $html by using mb_detect_encoding($html) and it output UTF-8. For the header if you mean by header("Content-type:application/pdf"); , i try it and still not worked.

Comment: anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that default font provided within dompdf does not support chinese character. You have to insert your own custom fonts in order to display the chinese words. Refer here [Insert Custom Font](http://www.obstrum.xyz/2017/05/unable-to-display-chinese-character-in.html) on how to insert and use custom fonts in dompdf.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use this package:

```
composer require vatttan/apdf
```

[Documents](https://github.com/vatttanweb/APdf)